# GridSplitter - Infinite width

Tags: wpf

[image]

Simple GridSplitter is behaving strangely in a sense that when I move it left beyond MinWidth, the other column expands infinitely. What am I missing here?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="holdergrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">           
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width ="*" MinWidth="300"/>                
            <ColumnDefinition Width ="425"  MinWidth="300"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="Left"></Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Right"></Button>
        <GridSplitter Name="GridSplitterFolders" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column ="1" Width ="10" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndCurrent" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: try `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"`

Answer (score 1):

Add a columnDefinition with Width set to Auto to house the GridSplitter itself and change the ResizeBehavior to PreviousAndNext.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="*" MinWidth="300"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width ="425"  MinWidth="300"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
    <GridSplitter HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              Grid.Column="1" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
              Width="5" Background="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <Label Content="Right" Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This works, but try moving the splitter over the limit left... now when you try moving it again, it does not at first until you drag the previous overshot distance first. It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

feO2x is right. Infinite width occurs when GridSplitter has mixed * and pixel values.

Correctly working example of horizontal GridSplitter should have:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" MinWidth="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" MinWidth="200"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

And

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="6" Style="{StaticResource gridSplitterStyleVertical}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"
                ResizeDirection="Columns">
```

Notice

```
HorizontalAlignment="Center"
```

Itis also important to have this in order it to work properly

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is a bug that occurs when at least one of the column defintions is set to a pixel value. If you change your columns definition to a star value, then everything is fine. Check out this modified version of your code:

```
<Window x:Class="Gridsplitter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="Holdergrid" MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Path=ActualWidth}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="300" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400" MinWidth="300" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"></Button>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"></Button>
            <GridSplitter Name="GridSplitterFolders" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column ="1" Width ="5" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"/>
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ElementName=Holdergrid, Path=ActualWidth, StringFormat=Actual Width: {0}}"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Holdergrid, Path=Width, StringFormat=Width: {0}}" Margin="10 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Holdergrid, Path=MaxWidth, StringFormat=Max Width: {0}}" Margin="10 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When you drag the grid splitter to the left side, the right column will grow somewhat indefinitely, even exceeding the MaxWidth that I restricted. If you replace `Width="400"` with `Width="*"` on the third column definition, it works correctly. Obviously, that is the only way to make it work.

Comment: If you only use column definitions with star or auto grid length, you can remove the `MaxWidth` restriction on the Grid itself.